# C/C++ Run/Debug configuration in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I am new to C/C++ development in Eclipse and trying to configure Eclipse. I'm working in a Linux environment with GNU GCC and my toolchain is detected by Eclipse. As given in the Eclipse documentation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEIpa.png), I opened **Run**>>**Run configurations**. But the **C/C++ Local** tab is not there.

This is all I get.

[image: screenshot from run configurations]

But when I build a sample helloworld program, it's being built correctly.

[image: console output after building]

Any idea why this happens?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEIpa.png) http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_com.htm

Comment: I presume you did install the CDT plugins, right? C/C++ development is not supported by the base Eclipse install.

Comment: yes I did. :)
help >> Install new software and then installed necessary CDT packages

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as you. I was able to create and build one c/c++ project, but I couldn't run/debug it. Actually, I installed wrong CDT (CDT Visual C++ Support). Next I installed correct CDT (c/c++ development tools) and after one eclipse restart I had c/c++ application inside of Run Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  While hunting around, I found that the configuration types it shows you are filtered, even when the filter button in the dialog is unselected.  In your dialog, click on the little downward arrow triangle at the middle of the top of your window.
[Run configuration dialog filter pulldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJdF.png)

If you see any of the checkboxes selected (including Filter Closed Projects, Filter Deleted/Unavailable Projects, Filter Configuration Types, etc.) then uncheck them.  After doing this, you should see more available configuration types, including for C/C++.